cannot read properties of undefind - compaling error
In office I am working on linux, but at home on windows. I copied the repository everything's the same like in work but I can't work from home.

I did npm install. In office everything is working fine :(

Please don't post code or error messages as pictures but as text. And also show the relevant parts of the code ...

that error suggests that transactons.pl is undfined

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?, then please [edit] your question accordingly.


Not clear how you copied repo (git clone, or you just copied files). But anyway try to delete node_modules folder and run npm i
Check the node version if it's the same on Linux and Windows
Check if environment variables are also copied properly


I did git clone like should I do. Ok, I'll try it
